# The page isn’t redirecting properly after upgrading to Nginx 1.17?

Tags: nginx

Firstly, My nginx 1.14 configuration was working. After upgrading to nginx mainline 1.17 my nginx stop working. My default.conf is shown below. Any idea what changed since? Where should I look and correct my nginx default configuration?

Secondly, anything other than `mobile.mysite.com/admin1`, `admin2`, `admin3`, `admin4` must redirect to default `index.html` file. But I couldn't add that either. Any idea?

**UPDATE-1:** 
The mobile.mysite.com/admin1 looks working but mobile.mysite.com/admin1/**** or mobile.mysite.com/admin1/*****/**** not redirecting... Any idea?

**UPDATE-2:** 
When I type **h##ps://mobile.mysite.com/admin1/KH/login**

it shows on address bar as
**h##ps:// mobile.mysite.com/admin1/KH/index.html**

```
server {
    charset UTF-8;
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name  mobile.mysite.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/host.access.log main;

    location = / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }

    # redirect error pages to the static page
    error_page 401 402 403 404 405 500 502 503 504 index.html;
    location = /index.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        internal;
    }

    # Deny access to .htaccess files
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

    # Deny access to hidden files (beginning with a period)
    location ~ /\. {
         deny all;
    }


    if ($host = mobile.mysite.com/admin1) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 


    if ($host = mobile.mysite.com/admin2) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 


    if ($host = mobile.mysite.com/admin3) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 


    if ($host = mobile.mysite.com/admin4) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 

}


server {
    charset UTF-8;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    server_name  mobile.mysite.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mobile.mysite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mobile.mysite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    # redirect admin1
    location /admin1 {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass "http://192.168.1.101:3000/";
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_404;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
    }


    # redirect admin2
    location /admin2 {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass "http://192.168.1.102:3000/";
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_404;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
    }


    # redirect admin3
    location /admin3 {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass "http://192.168.1.103:3000/";
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_404;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
    }


    # redirect admin4
    location /admin4 {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass "http://192.168.1.104:3000/";
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_404;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
    }


    # redirect error pages to the static page
    error_page 401 402 403 404 405 500 502 503 504 index.html;
    location = /index.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        internal;
    }


    # deny access to .htaccess files
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

    # Deny access to hidden files (beginning with a period)
    location ~ /\. {
         deny all;
    }

    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ )
    {
         return 404;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @rg305 on h##ps://community.letsencrypt.org/t/the-page-isn-t-redirecting-properly-after-upgrading-to-1-17/109196/7 just finalized and its working. I am using conf.d/default.conf and I don’t use site-enabled or site-available folder. Here is what I add and worked. I  made simpler 80 server as shown below. And then I added

```
proxy_http_version  1.1;
proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Upgrade    $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection     "upgrade";
```

for each app and its working even beter than before. If I type admin1, or admin1/***** proxy_pass is working. anything other than admin1, or admin1/***** redirect to index html file.

add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

```
server {
    charset UTF-8;
    listen      80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name  mobile.mysite.com;

    # HTTP REDIRECT
    location / {
    return 301 https://mobile.mysite.com$request_uri;
    }

}


server {
    charset UTF-8;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot

    server_name  mobile.mysite.com;
    root /var/www/html/;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mobile.mysite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mobile.mysite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    # LOGING    
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/host.error.log  warn;

    # index.html fallback
    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # reverse proxy admin1
    location /admin1 {
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade    $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection     "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass "http://192.168.1.101:3000/";
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_404;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
    }

    # reverse proxy admin2
    location /admin2 {
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade    $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection     "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass "http://192.168.1.102:3000/";
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_404;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
    }

    # reverse proxy admin3
    location /admin3 {
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade    $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection     "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass "http://192.168.1.103:3000/";
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_404;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
    }

    # reverse proxy admin4
    location /admin4 {
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade    $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection     "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass "http://192.168.1.104:3000/";
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_404;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
    }




    # redirect error pages to the static page
    error_page 401 402 403 404 405 index.html;
    location = /index.htm {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        internal;
    }


    # redirect server error pages to the static page
    error_page 500 502 503 504 index.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        internal;
    }


    # deny access to .htaccess files
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

    # Deny access to hidden files (beginning with a period)
    location ~ /\. {
         deny all;
    }

    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ )
    {
         return 404;
    }

}
```